# How can I add horizontal lines overlapping through a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, line

I'm making a simple bar chart using javascript. All styles are being done through javascript. I have a main container:

```
var mainContainer = document.getElementById(element);
var chartContainer = document.createElement("div");
chartContainer.class = "graphite-container";
$(chartContainer).css({
  "padding-left": "50px",
  "height": "100%",
  "border-width": "1px",
  "border-style": "solid",
  "border-color": "black",
  "width": "100%",
  "margin-top": "20px",
  "padding-top": "20px"
});
$(mainContainer).append(chartContainer);
```

And I have the lines that I want to put through the container for height markers:

```
var addLines = function(dataObj) {
var specs = Object.values(dataObj);
var highestNumber = 0;
for (i = 0; i < specs.length; i++) {
  if (specs[i] > highestNumber) {
    highestNumber = specs[i];
  }
}
var interval = Math.round(highestNumber / 5);

for (i = 0; i <= highestNumber ; i += interval) {
  var separator = document.createElement("hr");
  separator.class = "horizontal-line";
  var separatorHeight = separatorInterval + '%';
  $(separator).css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "width": "100%",
    "color": "black",
  });
  $(chartContainer).append(separator);
}
};
```

The only way I can get the lines to show is if I remove the "position: absolute", but then they're just at the top of the bars that I have. I try to set the margin bottom to separate them but that doesn't work. There must be some CSS rule that I'm forgetting.

Comment: Did you try "bottom: 0" ?

Comment: You're not passing in the height that you calculate. Add: 'height': separatorHeight. Also, color only works on text, use "border": "1px solid black" instead.

Comment: I'm not passing the height that I calculate because height doesn't work period. For some reason all 5 of the lines are in the same place unless I don't use absolute positioning, but then they're just above everything.